# Dynamic SQL for trigger or rules for computed columns?

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I would like to keep some computed columns in several tables and columns (PostgreSQL). The calculation is the same but there might be practically any number of tables and columns. So if the input is table1.field1 then the calculated field is table1.field1_calculated . And so forth. I was thinking on using triggers to maintain this, one trigger per field. This would require passing in the table and the field name as arguments into the function, assembling a SQL statement and executing it. I do not want to rely on plpgsql as that might not be available everywhere and everything I can find about dynamic SQL in PostgreSQL is a) old b) says you need plpgsql for that.

So

1. Is there a way in PostgreSQL 9.4+ or perhaps 9.5+ to create and execute dynamic SQL without plpgsql?
2. Is there a better way than triggering this function containing said dynamic SQL?

Ps. I am aware of the function/column notation trick but that doesn't really work here. For 2. I am suspecting rules might work but can't figure out how.

Comment: PL/pgSQL **is** available everywhere.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpgsql-overview.html "In PostgreSQL 9.0 and later, PL/pgSQL is installed by default. However it is still a loadable module, so especially security-conscious administrators could choose to remove it". Also, I am reasonably sure I saw a question while researching this asking about an error stemming from PL/pgSQL being available but not installed in the database for the user.

Comment: 9.0 and anything before that aren't supported any more. Why don't you have control over the environment where you deploy your application? If your application requires PL/pgSQL why would anyone remove it? There is no alternative to dynamic SQL then a procedural language - but any other is even less likely to be available.

Comment: I am coding a Drupal module. I have zero control over where it'll be deployed. (But this question is not Drupal specific since this functionality doesn't even exist in Drupal yet, that's the problem :) ).